# Cannot find Tensorflow native library for OS

Tags: java, maven, tensorflow, jar

I am trying to export my image classifier program wrote in Java, made with Tensorflow (added through Maven) into a runnable jar file with all the dependencies (including Tensorflow of course) so it can work on external computers.

Once the jar done, I tried running it onto multiple Windows 7 (or more recent) computers: on half of them, the program was working correctly, but on the other half (including mine), it was not: indeed, when the image detection event was fired thanks to a button on the GUI, an error appears on the command line:

`Exception in thread "Awt-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find Tensorflow native library for OS: windows, architecture: x86`

Also, when I click again on the button, an new error is thrown:

`Exception in thread "Awt-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.tensorflow.Tensor`

Every computer where I have been testing my jar has a recent JRE version at least installed. Some of the pc where the jar is working don't even have Python and/or Tensorflow installed in any way while mine for example has everything correctly installed.

Here is my pom.xml: https://hastebin.com/oxidunasaw.xml

Can you help me figure out what is the problem, and give me solutions in order to make the jar work in every computers?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The TensorFlow Java distributions include a (platform/architecture dependent) native library. More information in the speaker nodes of the [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vQ6DzxNTBrJo7K5P8t5_rBRGnyJoPUPBVOJR4ooHCwi4TlBFnIriFmI719rDNpcQzojqsV58aUqmBBx/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000&slide=id.g306175dd89_0_31) linked from the [TensorFlow Java samples](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/samples/languages/java).

The error message suggests that for some reason either the native library could not be found, or the one packaged in the `org.tensorflow:libtensorflow_jni` Maven artifact is not compatible with the OS version/architecture you're running on. This can happen for a variety of reasons, such as an incompatible version of the libc shared libraries.

You can get more debugging information by running the JVM with `-Dorg.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.DEBUG=1`, which will print out diagnostic information about the trouble with the packaging.

Hope that helps.

P.S. I also noticed that you're using version 1.1.0-rc2 of the Java API, which is almost a year old. You may want to move to a newer version.